# Airflow Fernet Key Rotation InvalidToken Error

Tags: python, airflow

Attempting to rotate my [fernet key in Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/fernet.html). The documentation lists three steps I should take to perform this task:

```
1. Set fernet_key to new_fernet_key,old_fernet_key
2. Run airflow rotate-fernet-key to re-encrypt existing credentials with the new fernet key
3. Set fernet_key to new_fernet_key
```

Following these steps, I set my `fernet_key` field in my airflow.cfg to the following:

```
fernet_key = PgYclMAx5ovWHa3MEE2Qt4oIOPoB70U64frFnwBzTtc=,d3itG077fUgVXkTfLd2EEA6y7ShulLjGRYXwgEq78j4=
```

Note: I've confirmed `d3itG077fUgVXkTfLd2EEA6y7ShulLjGRYXwgEq78j4=` is the old key. I also ensured that I used the fernet library to generate the new key, so they should be properly formed.

When I attempt to run `airflow rotate-fernet-key` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/rotate_fernet_key_command.py", line 28, in rotate_fernet_key
    conn.rotate_fernet_key()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/connection.py", line 265, in rotate_fernet_key
    self._extra = fernet.rotate(self._extra.encode('utf-8')).decode()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 183, in rotate
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Airflow version: 2.0.2

Python version: 3.8.5

Any ideas on why this could be occurring?

Comment: Did you restart all your services after rotating the fernet key?

Comment: @kaxil Unfortunately, I'm unable to rotate at all. The `rotate-fernet-key` command fails with an `InvalidToken` error

Comment: Does `airflow connections list` give you an error too>

Comment: @kaxil Nope. I believe the original fernet key is valid, so the connections and variables commands all function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For this case it means that the old key is already invalid, you need to find the correct old key.

In my case, I imported the database from the production environment so I need to put that key in place of the old key.